# How can I export .mesh files?

Tags: mesh, export

I'm using blender2Org to export .mesh file but what I get is `.material`, `.mesh.xml` and `.scene`. How can I get the `.mesh` file? My game engine use only `.mesh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution :

- download the [Ogre Command-line Tools](http://www.ogre3d.org/download/tools)
- create a new folder in your root directory named OgreCommandLineTools ( C:\ for me )*
- copy paste what you have downloaded from Ogre command-line Tools in the previous folder

now when you export your 3d model with blender2Org you will find the .mesh file